# Login-Window on anonymous access in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010, authentication, anonymous, http-status-code-401

Whenever we deploy our sharepoint website we have pages that show a login-window to anonymous users (and after that a 401 if the user does not login). This login-window disappears once we login from any machine. After that: The anonymous users can watch that site, too.

The Page is in a published state and has a major version.

This is no big problem for us as we can solve it like described above. I just wonder what causes this weird behaviour. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

It really was a strange reason. (Easy once I found out). This time it is surprisingly no sharepoint-error.

The problem was the following: We use a webpart that generated thumbnails in the correct size so our users can assign pictures of any size. These thumbnails are then saved in the cache. Now our users added the sharepoint-thumbnail of those pictures which lie in a protected area.

Now when logged in the protected images are collected and saved in the Cache which can be accessed by anyone.

Simple reason - complex error behaviour :)